# What will happen if I lose all my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

What will happen if I lose all my reputation by asking bullshit question?

Comment: Don't worry, questions on meta don't count towards your rep : )

Comment: Don't worry you can again earn it :)

Comment: That was funny. @Freddy

Answer (score 7):

Your reputation will go to 1, and you won't be able to do anything except post, suggest edits, and accept answers. If you ask too many low quality questions after being asked not to, there's a chance you will get suspended, too.

Please don't deliberately ask bad questions.

Comment: I suspect that the automatic suspension will occur long before reaching 1 reputation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - low quality question blocking is only turned on on a few sites and Physics isn't one of them. Low quality answer blocking is turned on on all sites.

Comment: @MichaelHampton On our site the automatic suspension is only enabled for answers. Though we may request it to be  enabled for questions, looking at the way things are going.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm pretty sure Manishearth is talking about manual suspension here. We do tend to notice cases where someone asks 15 or 20 negatively voted and/or deleted questions without any positive contribution.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually pretty hard to lose all of your reputation.  There is a major imbalance between reputation gains and losses.  For example, if a question gets upvoted you get 5 reputation but if it gets downvoted you only lose 2.  See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

You'd have to put in a lot more effort to lose reputation than you have to put in to gain it.  You'd get suspended way before that happened.

Comment: Well, you'd be surprised. There's something called an [answer ban](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans), which is extremely rare to hit, even on sites like [so]. Yet [someone hit it](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/i-cant-answer-now-any-question-on-physics-stackexchange). But yeah, one needs to make an effort.

Comment: But a upvote is counted against a downvote. If you are upvoted and downvoted equally they will just cancel out.

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed: An upvote gives you +5 rep (for questions) and +10 rep (for answers), but a downvote gives you -2 rep (for questions or answers)

Comment: @DIMension10 Suppose in a question you have 1 upvote and 1 downvote, your reputation will be unchanged. Not that you will be awarded +3!

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed: You *will* get +3.

Comment: It did't happened to me.

Comment: I have 4 downvote and 1 upvote in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86524/how-momentum-energy-is-distributed-in-a-elastic-collision) but my reputation is downvoted -6

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed: No, I can see the vote counts, and you just got 3 downvotes, no upvotes.